# jQuery - Strange error when a click event is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
function GetPriceForChildren(Price) {
    if(ChildrenItem == 1){
        var OnePercent =  Price / 100;
        var TwentyPercent = 20 * OnePercent;
        var FinalPrice = Price + TwentyPercent;
        FinalPrice = FinalPrice.toFixed(2)
        return FinalPrice;
    }
    if(ChildrenItem == 0){
        return Price;
    }   
}

        $('.ColorImages').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                $(".ColorImages").removeClass("SelectColor");
                $( ".ColorImages" ).removeClass("ColorImagesSelected");
                $( this ).addClass( "ColorImagesSelected" );
                var ImageLink = $(".ColorImages.ColorImagesSelected").attr( "imageLink" );
                var SelectedColorName = $(".ColorImages.ColorImagesSelected").attr( "alt" );

                $("#PRODUCTCOLOR").val(SelectedColorName);

                 $('#AnimationRotator').attr('data','http://www.sportsdirect.com/images/images360/' + ImageLink + '.swf');

                 var ColorNumber = $( this ).attr( "imageLink" );
                 $('#LoadingImage').show();                 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'CheckColorPrice.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            url: '<?php echo $LINK;?>',
                            ColorId: ColorNumber
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {                              
                                $("#PRICE").text("£ " + GetPriceForChildren(data["price"]));
                                var lev = <?PHP echo $PoundCurrency; ?> * GetPriceForChildren(data["price"]);
                                lev = lev.toFixed(2);
                                $("#lev").text(lev + " лв.");
                                $("#PRODUCTPRICE").val(lev);
                                $('#SizeOfProduct').find('option').remove().end().append('<option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>');
                                var AutoIncreasment = 0;
                                $.each(data.sizenames, function(index, sizenames) {                             
                                $('#SizeOfProduct').append('<option value="'+ sizenames +'" size-number="'+ (AutoIncreasment++) +'">'+ sizenames +'</option>'); 
                                });
                                $('.ColorImagesNOColor').fadeOut();
                                $("#Broi").val("1");
                                $('#LoadingImage').hide();

                        }
                    });

            });

        });
```

When i click on a div element with class `ColorImages` I receive a very strange error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: FinalPrice.toFixed is not a function

    GetPriceForChildren @ purchase-product:642
    $.each.$.click.$.ajax.success @ purchase-product:693
    n.Callbacks.j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
    n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
    x @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
    n.ajaxTransport.send.b @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
```

I do not understand this at all. I am wondering where the mistake is and it seems i can not find it for hours ago.
Can you please tell me where is my mistake and how can i fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just put a `console.log(FinalPrice)` before `FinalPrice = FinalPrice.toFixed(2)` and see what are you getting. Is it undefined or null?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `GetPriceForChildren` function, step through the code and check the values (type, value, ...)

Comment: @palash I get console `1.000.2`.

Comment: Since all the calculations are based off of hard coded numbers or previous calculations except for `price`, I imagine that `price` is not coming in to the function as the value you're expecting it to be. In the top of the function add `console.log(price);` as the first line and see what value is being passed as the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data["price"]` is not a number but probably an String. Try doing

```
$("#PRICE").text("£ " + GetPriceForChildren(parseFloat(data["price"])));
var lev = <?PHP echo $PoundCurrency; ?> * GetPriceForChildren(parseFloat(data["price"]));
```

parseFloat converts an string to a decimal number.

Comment: That's it! Can i make this conversation in the function ?

Comment: Sure add `Price = parseFloat(Price)` at the very begining of it and you should be ready to go

Comment: Typically it's a good idea to err on the side of caution and include the radix with the `parseFloat` (i.e. `parseFloat(Price, 10);`...

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to keep it simple